# How to get the fields' information from a SQL statement in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, select, field

I want to get fields' description from a SQL statement. That is, I want create a function, use a sql statement as the input parameter, returns a jsonb value to decribe the fields' information.

If I know the table name, I can do this:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema."columns"
WHERE "table_name"='TABLE-NAME'
```

But if I only have the select sql statement, such as `select 0::bigint as fid, 'A'::text as fname;`,how can I get the `column_name` and `data_type` In a function.

Below is the structure for then function when the I know the table name:

```
create or replace function public.getfieldsfromtable(vtable text)
    returns jsonb
    language 'plpgsql'
    cost 100
    volatile 
as $body$ declare
    jfields jsonb='[]'::jsonb;
begin
    select 
        array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) 
    into jfields
    from (
        select column_name, data_type
        from information_schema."columns"
        where "table_name"=vtable
    ) t;
    return jfields;
end;
$body$;
```

But What Can I Do If I Just Have A Select SQL Statement?

```
create or replace function public.getfieldsfromsql(vsql text)
    returns jsonb
    language 'plpgsql'
    cost 100
    volatile 
as $body$ declare
    jfields jsonb='[]'::jsonb;
begin
    ... what can i do?
    return jfields;
end;
$body$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easy, if you do it in C extension, but it is almost impossible in PL/pgSQL. For stored procedures, there is not an API, how to detect structure of result without query execution.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a simple example how to do it? Use C extension or Python extension. I just know some C and Python, but I never wrote any function with them.

Comment: you need to write interface over SPI interface - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html. You can look on https://github.com/postgres/postgres/tree/master/contrib/spi extension for inspiration.